Performing actual async background operation
I have a .NET Core service, and in my flow, I want to guarantee that caching the fetched data will happen after the flow ends.
i.e. that it won't have impact on the request latency at all
public async Task<Result> GetAndCacheAsync()
{
    var data = await GetFromDbAsync();

    _ = CacheDataAsync(data); // I want to **guarantee** this happens only after the method completes

    var results = await ProcessData(data);

    return results;
}

I tried to find solutions for this problem, but seems like all use the async-await Tasks mechanism, which doesn't guarantee it AFAIU, since the thread can start the "Cache task" that was created, before it resumes the "Main flow task".
What should be the solution to guarantee there is no user impact (request latency impact)?

as an aside: what you're doing here looks a lot like what HybridCache should be adding in .NET 9, but with additional benefits such as cache stampeded protection; then the entire thing becomes something like var data = await cache.GetOrCreateAsync("somekey", async _ => GetFromDbAsync()); (and yes, it includes deferred cache write, although it is achieved in a more nuanced way: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0e812ecaa9c053b2e1032183b2006a56ee19f0b4/src/Caching/Hybrid/src/Internal/DefaultHybridCache.StampedeStateT.cs#L84-L90)

So you want to invoke the CacheDataAsync method in a fire-and-forget fashion when the GetAndCacheAsync() task has completed, correct? I am asking because the terms you use ("Cache task", "Main flow task") are confusing.

@TheodorZoulias I want to fire-and-forget, but moreover - I want the task I fired will not  be executed for sure by the current thread before it finished the request's flow.
(meaning it won't have latency impact on the HTTP request)

It seems that you could use an event like RequestEnd, provided by the ASP.NET Core infrastructure, and fire the fire-and-forget task there. But I don't know if such an event exist. In case it doesn't exist, the requirement of firing the task after the end of the HTTP request might be impossible to enforce reliably. In that case the best you could do might be to interpose a Task.Delay and hope for the best.

I think guaranteeing that the caching happens after the flow is the wrong aim; instead, think of guaranteeing that the caching doesn't interrupt the flow, and beyond that, we don't care - it can happen in parallel or after. Otherwise we need to have a handle on the completion of the current thing, which seems burdensome.
And for this, we have simple options:
_ = Task.Run(() => CacheDataAsync(data));

If you really really want to defer until completion of the current flow, then you would need some kind of signal of that flow's completion - most likely the Task that represents the primary flow (although other mechanisms exist); from there you could, for example, use something like:
_ = Task.Run(async () => {
    await primaryFlow;
    await CacheDataAsync(data);
});

There is also primaryFlow.ContinueWith(...). In either event, you'd need to be a little cautious of "thread theft" (potentially interrupting the primary application loop). In reality, I think it is easier to sidestep this by using the simpler and safer approach.

Can you please explain why Task.Run behaves differently? Can't a Thread "decide" to execute the task's code before the ProcessData(data) code?

@Omer I covered that extensively already; yes, doing this the simple way, the two things are independent and may overlap - usually that's perfectly fine; as I said: it you really really need to avoid that, you'll need some additional hook to the completion of the logical thing you want to wait for - and that depends entirely on whatever is running this code, unless you add your own TaskCompletionSource layer

"usually that's perfectly fine" means it might still affect the flow's latency? I want to guarantee that it won't - meaning the current thread will first finish the GetAndCacheAsync code. Is it guaranteed in the _ = Task.Run(() => CacheDataAsync(data)); logic?

@Omer no, not in the least - although in reality it should be sufficiently independent that it doesn't matter; as I already said; to guarantee that, you need some kind of hook to whatever is running the current request/whatever; you can of course then await that thing; it sounds like you're using asp.net - another option might be to hook this in either an action result or middleware, but I strongly suspect that you're massively overcomplicating this; do you actually know that there's a genuine issue you're trying to solve here, that Task.Run doesn't work well for?

@Omer I'm not asking this entirely academically; I'm literally in the team that maintains asp.net, so I'm interested in what you're seeing here

I don't actually know it happens, but according to async-await logic, this case be the case. Would be interesting to have a built-in language keyword to say "queue this task, but keep running the remaining flow with the current thread". Thanks for the help!

that's exactly what Task.Run does; the question is simply "queue until when?" - Task.Run assumes "until a worker is available, creating a new worker periodically if needed", which is almost always absolutely fine (and I'm 99% sure would actually be fine for you here), where-as you seem to want "until the current request is complete"; as an aside, you should IMO stop thinking in terms of threads - when you're dealing in async/await: the thread is not yours, and can change at any await (there's some minutae here about sync-context, but that doesn't apply to asp.net)
